# Not able to install Ubuntu or any other Linux distros on my laptop

Tags: lenovo, games

I have a Lenovo IdeaPad gaming laptop with RYZEN 5 and nvidia 1650 , but whenever I tried to install to install any Linux distro like Ubuntu , fedora it is not installing just showing
1.090313] integrity: Problem loading X.509 certificate -65
For your reference I had already disabled secure boot option and tried adding "nomodset parameter" but still no success...
As I am quite new at Linux , your help will be appreciated

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Is UEFI Secure Boot on? Similar model worked, but no real details: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2468305&page=2&p=14113811#post14113811

Comment: I am on Fedora Linux 38(Workstation edition)and the UEFI secure boot is disabled already and now I am able to install it successfully using (nomodset parameter) but whenever I am trying to install the nvidia drivers after the reboot the screen wents black with a flickering cursor (installed the nvidia drivers using rpm fusion) tried multiple times to install the driver but nothing is working